# Why can't I print this in windows ( ه҈҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉ ')?

Tags: windows, powershell, unicode

I got this from the following question: [What are these ? ه҈҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302283/what-are-these-%D9%87%D2%88%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89%D2%89)

I can't get this to print in windows powershell. I tried using `chcp 65001`. BTW I can print `北京` but not ه҈҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it treats combining diacriticals as separate characters & cannot actually combine them.

You can see the same here - the first is formatted as code, so no combining occurs, the second allows them to combine, as a regular text editor would.

`t ه҈҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉`
t ه҈҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉

If you look at how these were done by opening this answer in [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1725952/edit), you'll see the only difference is in forcing the first into 'code' attributes.
This is ignoring any glyphs that may not render at all - life's too short to track them all down - this was just a simple copy/paste.